# Решение систем уравнений на java

Tags: java, math

Можете подсказать библиотеку, которая решает cистемы уравнений.
Например:

```
x + y^3 = 29
x^5 - y^2 - 23 = 0

x = 2
y = 3
```

Если решает по шагам, вообще идеально

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, это слау. решается методом гауса. В универе писал реализацию для этих целей https://github.com/izebit/Library/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/izebit/numerical_methods/Lup.java

Comment: Я уже делал такую прогу, но парсер моего изготовления был довольно плох и поэтому переменные не могли перемножатся, не было sin  и cos  и тд